# PrimeNG header template add title

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I need to template primeNG p-datatable header. I simply want to add a title to the header. I'm trying this:

```
<p-column field="field" header="header" [style]="{'width':'100px'}">
     <ng-template ptemplate="header">
          <span title="header"></span>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-template let-cell="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          <span title="cell.field">{{cell.field}}</span>
     </ng-template>
<p-column>
```

It works only for cell content.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
header text is showed. I think it taken from p-column header. When I hover over this text, span title doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you enter text in the header span ? `<span title="header">Put some text here</span>`

Comment: Because it put the header from p-column. My problem is that title doesn't work when I hover over the text showed.

Comment: SOLVED: very stupid error. ptemplate instead of pTemplate!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will do what you expect but if you want to make the tooltip visible, replace

```
<span title="header"></span>
```

with

```
<div title="header">&nbsp;</div>
```